# Screen out of the monitor, how to fix

Tags: screen, monitor, borders

The screen is cut out borders of the monitor. It doesn't give me problem with the vga cable, but when I use the HDMI it does this unfunny joke.
I have no idea how to resolve, in windows there is a functionality in the panel of NVIDIA that allows me to regulate manually with "4 arrows". Is there something similar in ubuntu? It seems that I cannot use anything else other than the imposed resolutions.
https://www.aranzulla.it/wp-content/contenuti/cent2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when setting up a television as a second monitor.

You may be able to resolve the issue using the buttons (or dials) on the monitor itself.

Most modern monitors will have a menu system with the ability to adjust settings like brightness and contrast.

Look for options like Zoom, Stretch, Center, Aspect ratio.

Comment: The proble is that I don't find the remote, and the lateral buttons don't have an "ok" function, so I can't change the settings of the monito/tv. I hoped there was a way to set this thing from the pc.

Comment: Try pressing the up and down arrows simultaneously for "ok"

Comment: Sadly that combination does not work.